# NodeJS getting stuck in callback

Tags: node.js

Im having troubles where my node app all a sudden starts to consume a lot of CPU. Im suspecting that the function below gets stuck somehow..

```
Client.prototype.countActiveChatsRedis = function (userID, agentID, obj, callback) {
    var count = 0;

    pub.keys("widgetActive:" + userID + ":*", function(err, key) {

        if(err !== null) {
            console.log("Redis error..... --> " + err);
            callback(count, obj);           
        }

        if(key && key.length > 0) {
            pub.mget(key, function(err, data) {
                if(data) {
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
                        if(data[i]) {
                            var arr = data[i].split(",");

                            if(arr[2] == agentID) {
                                if (Number(arr[3]) > 0) {
                                    count++;
                                }                           
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    callback(count, obj);
                }
            });         
        } else {
            callback(count, obj);           
        }
    });
}
```

Any ideas what the problem could be? Any case where it could avoid sending the callback?

This function runs around 50 times per second.

Answer (score 3):

It is bad practice to use KEYS in a production environment. To quote the Redis master himself:

> Warning: consider KEYS as a command that should only be used in
>   production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
>   when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
>   for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
>   layout. Don't use KEYS in your regular application code. If you're
>   looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider
>   using SCAN or sets.

Whenever you add a key with this prefix, just add it to a set called "widgetActive" the user's id or any other data you need.
you can also use HASH if you need to save some data for each entry.

Comment: Could you give a small example? =) Not sure that i follow

Answer (score 0):

you should always **return** your callbacks to make sure that your function terminates correctly and returns the control to the calling context:

```
Client.prototype.countActiveChatsRedis = function (userID, agentID, obj, callback) {
var count = 0;

pub.keys("widgetActive:" + userID + ":*", function(err, key) {

    if(err !== null) {
        console.log("Redis error..... --> " + err);
        return callback(count, obj);           
    }

    if(key && key.length > 0) {
        pub.mget(key, function(err, data) {
            if(data) {
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
                    if(data[i]) {
                        var arr = data[i].split(",");

                        if(arr[2] == agentID) {
                            if (Number(arr[3]) > 0) {
                                count++;
                            }                           
                        }
                    }
                }

                return callback(count, obj);
            }
        });         
    } else {
        return callback(count, obj);           
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Do you think this could have been the problem?

Comment: No I don't. I just wrote this for fun

Answer (score 0):

It's stucked because in the case where there is no data, no callback is being called.

```
pub.mget(key, function(err, data) {
   if(data) {
     for(var i = 0; i < data.length;i++) {
        if(data[i]) {
          var arr = data[i].split(",");

          if(arr[2] == agentID) {
            if (Number(arr[3]) > 0) {
               count++;
            }                           
          }
        }
     }

     // callback(count, obj);  // <==== move this callback outside of if (data)
   }
   callback(count, obj);  // this ensures that callback always gets called

 });
```